# LTI 1.3 - Access token - Error validating assertion: Unknown validation exception

Tags: integration, lti

I'm trying to create a lti 1.3 integration in Brightspace (POC), and I was able to get to the point where the tool endpoint is launch. At this endpoint I'm trying to get access token in order to get the membership data, so I send the request (for the access token) with the relevant scope and all the credentials with no success. I also added to the url address the relevant parameters as the documentation shows.

I think that at this point I should get the access token with no problems, because when I was trying to integrate with moodle I successfully received the access token back. I know there is a standard in all LMSs but Is there any specific adjustment to integrate with Brightspace.

Comment: What is the error the LMS returns? If the access token(id token) is not present it should have thrown an error message. Did you try catching that error?

Comment: Yes, the error that I'm getting is 401 (unauthorized), and that is weird because it happening after I generate access token to the relevant scope.